# sql command to display highest repeated field in a column

Tags: sql

How to display the highest repeated field in a column in sql ?

for eg if a column contains:

```
jack
jack
john
john
john
```

how to display the maximum repeated field (i.e) john from the above column?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? Postgres?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select chairman
from mytable
group by chairman
HAVING COUNT(*) = (
select TOP 1 COUNT(*)
from mytable
group by chairman
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC)
```

Comment: you should also consider ties `:)` example 3 john and 3 jack.

Comment: What is the DBMS you are using?

Comment: Updated answer for ms sql server 2008

Answer (score 0):

```
select name from persons
group by name
having count(*) = (
  select count(*) from persons
  group by name
  order by count(*) desc
  limit 1)
```

Comment: @user2815781: It does not say that in your question, so we have to guess such things.

Comment: Yep, just checked, my crystal ball is broken.